# Inside the for loop the array should be classify between prime and not prime number, but the value return is zero for notPrime and Prime array

Tags: c++, for-loop

```
#include <fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
bool isPrime(int n) 
{ 
// Corner case 
if (n <= 1) 
    return false; 
  
// Check from 2 to n-1 
for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) 
    if (n % i == 0) 
        return false; 
  
return true; 
} 

int main() {
//initialie the array size
int arr[100000];
int arrStore[100000];
int arrPrime[100000];
int arrNotPrime[100000];
ifstream is("file.txt");
int cnt= 0;
int x;
   
// check that array is not already full
while (cnt < arr[100000] && is >> x)
   
   
// and read integer from file
arr[cnt++] = x;
// print the integers stored in the array

cout<<"\nThe integers are:"<<"\n";
```

#### here the array doesn't differentiate

> the value return from the array is all 0

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  cout << arr[i] <<endl;
  isPrime(arr[i]) ? cout << " is prime number\n" : cout << " not Prime number\n";
  isPrime(arr[i]) ? arrPrime[i] = arr[i] : arrNotPrime[i] = arr[i];
```

> I tried to delete the boolean line and the codes is working fine  knowing whether the value in array is prime or not but the time I try to put into two different arrays, the value return is 0

```
}
//check if there is prime number in array
cout<< arrPrime[0]<<endl;
  

return 0;

   
//close the file
//.close();
}
```

Comment: `cnt < arr[100000]` compares the value of `cnt` with the value at index `100000` in the array. And that index is *out of bounds* leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: `cnt < arr[100000]` where `arr[100000]` is not initialed, do you mean `cnt < 100000`?

Comment: You should also check that you opened the file successfully.

Comment: Also remember that local variables are not initialized, their values or contents will be *indeterminate*. Using indeterminate values leads to *undefined behavior* as well.

Comment: Lastly, on almost all systems local variables (including arrays) will be stored on the stack. The stack is a limited resource, on Windows the default stack-size for a process is a single MiB. Assuming that `sizeof(int) == 4` (which is common on all PC-like systems in use today) then your four arrays alone will be around 1.5 MiB. If you don't know how many elements you might get as input, then use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: You could speed up you ```isPrime``` function by iterating whilst ```i <= n/2```

Comment: thank you guys for the comments . . found the problems

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some mistakes in your while loop.
1)You are are accessing wrong memory location.i.e(arr[100000])
2)Second your  cnt  variable will increase if some how loop run,and on some stage it will be possible that value in cnt will be greater than arr[index].

```
  while (cnt < arr[100000] && is >> x)
        // and read integer from file
        arr[cnt++] = x;
    // print the integers stored in the array
```